# WPF/C#: WPF Path Maker Tool/Sample?

Tags: c#, wpf, path, markup

I am just wondering if it's possible to create a WPF application that allows users to use a certain pen to plot directions to make a certain path and able to display the path data.

The idea is almost the same with this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gavingear/archive/2007/02/15/intoducing-pathmaker-a-tool-for-creating-path-markup-for-wpf-e.aspx

I also found a good sample where I can draw lines and stuff inside the canvas: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DrawTools.aspx

I'm just looking for a good head start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jesema is another one that might be helpful for you:

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/jasema/

If you want something where you can draw stuff inside a canvas, there's livegeometry

http://livegeometry.codeplex.com/

but that one has the path data abstracted away (that's more similar to your draw tools example).

Hope those help!

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is quite old, but I found that [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) supports save to XAML.

See this article: http://www.software-architects.com/devblog/2008/01/13/Graphic-In-XAML-And-WPF